# TFS: Latest_Version_ in branch properties is different from Latest _Changeset: WHY?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I am using Visual Studio 2012 with TFS for version control; also cmd.exe to run tf commands.
For the branch in which I am working, the changeset (CS) in my workspace is older (lower) than the latest changeset on the server.

The latest CS on the server is 12066, according to the history listing for this branch.
(Also the result of command "tf history . /r /noprompt /stopafter:1 /version:T")

The CS of my workspace (for the same branch) is 12015 (the result of the command: "tf history . /r /noprompt /stopafter:1 /version:W")

So far, all clear. But then I open the properties pop-up for the branch in VS: Source control explorer > r-click the branch > Advanced > Properties

A Properties pop-up appears and it sais:
Latest Version: 12046 (I expected latest changeset here, being 12066, according to history listing)
Workspace Version: 11108 (I expected my workspace version here, being 12015)

I get the same information when I run the command "tf info" ("tf properties" in VS2010) for this branch.

Why is Latest version in properties different from latest version in history?
Why is Workspace version in properties different from the workspace version in the history command with /version:W?

I consulted the help page for the properties command,but that still left me confused. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzy14b58(v=vs.100).aspx)

=====comment on 1st answer (it is too long for commenting directly on your answer) ====

If I understand you correctly, the history listing for 3 branches, stemming from 1 parent, must be the same.
But, it is not: The Changeset on the top is different for each branch; also, reading the checkin comments, and checking the details of the changeset,  the history listing for each branch is different, and really only lists the changes that are done for that branch.

Devs (= Parent)  12066 (the highest of the 3 below)

-- FooBranch1   10139

-- FooBranch2   12066

-- FooBranch3   12047

@Dylan:

> then all changesets between 11109 to 12015 are changesets that don't affect that branch.

This really does not apply: in fact: most of these changesets affected this branh; it is the most active branch of the 3 I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know for sure but here's my theory (you'd have to consult your history to confirm/deny it):

The branch properties pop-up is only showing you the relevant versions for that branch (so check-ins that affected the branch).  Whereas the history command is looking at all changesets in TFS.

So the latest changeset on the server is 12066, but the latest changeset that affected that branch is 12046.

11108 would be a changeset to that branch, then all changesets between 11109 to 12015 are changesets that don't affect that branch.  And you did a Get Latest last at changeset 12015.  So the last changeset to that branch you have in your local workspace is 11108, but you have all the non-branch changesets up to 12015.

Comment: Yep!  A changeset applies to the entire repository.  So you can have changeset 5 of `$/Foo` locally, the server can be at changeset 6 which *didn't touch `$/Foo` at all*, and if you do a get latest, your workspace version will now be 6, despite the fact that changeset 6 didn't make changes in your working folder.

Comment: The answer does not explain my situation: See my additonal comment in my initial question.